# TypeScript - How to override declaration in lib.d.ts?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The issue is the following:

I need to instantiate a `File` using the constructor that takes 2 arguments `(byteArray, fileName)` and I need to create a TypeScript typing for that.

The definition for `File` in **lib.d.ts** is the following (line 11479):

```ts
declare var File: {
    prototype: File;
    new(): File;
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but:

- I cannot define constructors inside interfaces (which I can extend)
- I cannot extend declarations (on which I can create the constructor I want)

Since modifying **lib.d.ts** is not a good idea, what do you guys suggest for me to be able to instantiate the file without having a TS error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: File API Specification here: http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-file - look for the constructor definition

Comment: Update2: I still dont know how to extend/overwrite the declaration, but as the File API is not part of IE9, I'm using another approach now.

Comment: The reason you cannot extend the type of `File` is due to how it is declared (using a type literal). Consider `declare var Object: ObjectConstructor`. `ObjectConstructor` is an interface and you can indeed extend it with new constructors.

Answer (score -1):

> - I cannot define constructors inside interfaces (which I can extend)

This is correct, an interface is just a blueprint for some part of functionality that is required by classes which extend it. What you're asking for would be `abstract` class, but this doesn't exist in TypeScript [(yet)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6).

> - I cannot extend declarations (on which I can create the constructor I want)

The whole point of interfaces is to be extended. Of course you could make your own class/interface that would define your expected usage on top of existing `File`.

Comment: Yes, but the File declaration in lib.d.ts is not an interface nor a class, thus cannot be extended.